# Where can I find the "terminal" program on OS X? 

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app

Where can I find this app, and where can I find instructions on how to use it?

My OS X is using the Dutch language settings.

Answer (score 3):

When your system is `Nederlands` locale, Terminal is in `Programma's`, `Hulpprogramma's`, `Terminal`. The Shortcut to the folder `Hulpprogramma's` in Finder is `Cmd-Shift-U`, or just select `Hupprogramma's` from the `Ga` menu in Finder.

Your shell is usually `bash`. Your best bet is to google "bash tutorial", or "unix command line tutorial" or something similar. If you find tutorials for Linux, that's usually fine too, there are not that many differences regarding the fundamentals, once your terminal window is open.

**Be aware that you can *seriously* mess up or destroy your system, or delete all of your data if you don't know what you're doing in Terminal!**

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone told me why this got voted down. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the down votes were for the "F--- word". Doesn't bother me, but might bother some.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for the info, changed the post accordingly. But that's what the flag button is for, if it's used inappropriately. Not when used to reinforce a statement, though. Seems some people can't be bothered to read the tooltips of what they click on.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal is under the Utilities folder, which is under Applications.  You launch it, then it presents you with a command line.  If you're not certain about what to do with it, you can cause damage to your OS.  It all depends on what you're looking to do with it.